# How to split two indexes in a list and not make a separate list in python

Tags: python, list, split

I have this list:

```
somestuff = [1,2,3,"4n5"]
```

I want to split the last index with the letter n. I am expecting this result:

```
>>>[1,2,3,4,5]
```

But when I use the .split() method on the last element of the list, like shown:

```
somestuff[-1] = somestuff[-1].split("n")
print(somestuff)
```

I get this result:

```
>>>[1,2,3,[4,5]]
```

How do I split the last index of a list and get my expectation? Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a range-replacement gives a succinct piece of code:

```
somestuff[-1:] = somestuff[-1].split('n')
```

The trick is telling python that you want to replace a range of elements with a different range of elements. The question's example replaces a single element with a range.

Answer (score 2):

another possible solution:

```
somestuff = [1,2,3,'4n5']
somestuff = somestuff + [int(x) for x in somestuff.pop().split('n')]
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can it meet your need?

```
newstuff = somestuff[:-1] + list(map(lambda x: int(x), somestuff[-1].split("n")))
newstuff # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```